# AWS DynamoDB java enhanced client mapping of dynamic set of properties

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, mapping

I try to find a way how to map the next json with a dynamic set of properties

```json
{
  "id" : "078c590a-f379-44d6-acfa-e4f4bf6d1c1e",
  "list_id" : "6a9b8285-c798-471a-912f-e8ab7492f935",

  "2b5b4df1-8f4d-4f6c-9c66-d5486c0639e9" : "USA",
  "1768bc2a-c0fd-403a-9770-974c7cf4f920" : "NY",
  "052d7982-4930-4fe8-91dc-e352a6e04112" : "5th avenue"
}
```

to the class

```java
public static class Asset {
   private String id;
   private String listId;
   private Map<String, String> metaData;
   // all getters and setters
}
```

using the AWS DynamoDB enhanced client.

Comment: Probably it's not possible to do it in DynamoDB natively. You can do mapping in Java however, possibly with reflection to map the JSON model to the DB model

Comment: The Enhanced Client - that is part of the AWS SDK for Java V2 maps a Java class like Asset to a DynamoDB table. See this doc topic for more information - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/dynamodb-enhanced-client.html

Comment: To map "id" and "listId" is pretty simple, but how to populate the "metaData" property I do not have any idea.

Comment: @corsair I would prefer to go for "metadata" as key which holds this UUID map. But if you still are looking to go for dynamic attribute map, here is an issue where we have a custom attribute-convertor used: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/1902